# How generate uniques grouping/summing one of the columns based on 2 criteria in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to get this one, but it's still hard for me.

**The data:**

```
let data = [
 [1, "Item A", "Food", 10],
 [2, "Item B", "Food", 5],
 [3, "Item C", "Food", 30],
 [4, "Item A", "Hygiene", 30],
 [4, "Item A", "Hygiene", 50],
 [6, "Item D", "Food", 7],
 [3, "Item C", "Food", 8],
 [1, "Item A", "Food", 60],
]
```

**Result**

```
let result = [
 [1, "Item A", "Food", 70],
 [2, "Item B", "Food", 5],
 [3, "Item C", "Food", 38],
 [4, "Item A", "Hygiene", 80],
 [6, "Item D", "Food", 7],
]
```

This is basic `reduce()` which I imagine would be the path to take, but how to set the criteria e generate unique rows?

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const initialValue = 0;
const sumWithInitial = array1.reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
  initialValue
);
console.log(sumWithInitial);
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: where is the first col coming from?

Comment: Sorry, @NinaScholz! Messed with it when generating the data. The idea it to sum based on 2 cols (1st and 2nd) as criteria. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a combined key for grouping.

```js
const
    data = [[1, "Item A", "Food", 10], [2, "Item B", "Food", 5], [3, "Item C", "Food", 30], [4, "Item A", "Hygiene", 30], [4, "Item A", "Hygiene", 50], [6, "Item D", "Food", 7], [3, "Item C", "Food", 8], [1, "Item A", "Food", 60]],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, a) => {
        const key = [0, 1].map(i => a[i]).join('|');
        if (r[key]) r[key][3] += a[3];
        else r[key] = [...a];
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I see it does it right. Thanks! So much to learn and on a Fri!?!?!? Need a cup of coffee... THANK YOU!

Comment: Quick question for my understanding here: Does ```[0, 1]``` in ```const key``` refer to cols 1 and 2 as the criteria set? Thank you!

Comment: yes, thats the case.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `map` with `findIndex`
I used also `reverse()`, `Object.values` with `Object.fromEntries` methods to get unique ones:

```js
let data = [
 [1, "Item A", "Food", 10],
 [2, "Item B", "Food", 5],
 [3, "Item C", "Food", 30],
 [4, "Item A", "Hygiene", 30],
 [4, "Item A", "Hygiene", 50],
 [6, "Item D", "Food", 7],
 [3, "Item C", "Food", 8],
 [1, "Item A", "Food", 60],
]
let objs = data.slice(); //in order to not mutate the source array data
let sumObjs = objs.map((curr, i) => {
let indexPrev = objs.findIndex(
    (item) => item[1] == curr[1] && item[2] == curr[2]
);
if (indexPrev != -1 && i != indexPrev) {
    //i != indexPrev to not accumelate the current one
    //indexPrev =! -1 means that one is exist
    objs[indexPrev][3] += curr[3];
}
return curr;
});
let result = Object.values(
Object.fromEntries(
    sumObjs.reverse().map((obj) => [JSON.stringify(obj[1]+obj[2]), obj])
)
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow. This one requires more coffee here... Thanks a lot!